# Empty space of tikz in standalone environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a newbie of Latex. Here is the figure i want to draw. To draw the deformed beam, I create a node (O) and draw two parallel arc. My question is how could I remove the empty space without delete this node. Or is there any better way to draw this figure. Thanks for you help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (O) at (2.5,2) {O};  %%node O

\path (O) ++(-60:5) coordinate (ee); 
\path (O) ++(-120:5) coordinate (oo); 
\draw[dashed][line width=.3pt] (oo) arc (-120:-60:5);


\path (O) ++(-60:4.5) coordinate (eeu); 
\path (O) ++(-120:4.5) coordinate (oou); 
\draw[dashed][line width=.3pt] (oou) arc (-120:-60:4.5);

\path (O) ++(-60:5.5) coordinate (eed); 
\path (O) ++(-120:5.5) coordinate (ood);
\draw[dashed][line width=.3pt] (ood) arc (-120:-60:5.5);
\draw[dashed][line width=.3pt] (ood) -- (oou);
\draw[dashed][line width=.3pt] (eed) -- (eeu);
\draw[-latex] (oo) -- ++(0:1) coordinate [label=below:$x$] (xx);
\draw[-latex] (oo) -- ++(90:1) coordinate [label=right:$y$] (yy);

\path (O) ++(-63:4.5) coordinate (eeuT); 
\path (O) ++(-117:4.5) coordinate (oouT); 
\draw[solid][line width=.5pt] (oouT) arc (-117:-63:4.5);

\path (O) ++(-57.5:5.5) coordinate (eedT); 
\path (O) ++(-122.5:5.5) coordinate (oodT);
\draw[solid][line width=.5pt] (oodT) arc (-122.5:-57.5:5.5);
\draw[solid][line width=.5pt] (oodT) -- (oouT);
\draw[solid][line width=.5pt] (eedT) -- (eeuT);


\draw[solid][line width=.3pt] (ee) -- ++(90:1.2) coordinate(vert);
\draw[solid][line width=.3pt] (ee) -- ++(120:1.2) coordinate(w);
\draw[solid][line width=.3pt] (ee) -- ++(145:1.2) coordinate(phi);
\pic [draw, ->, "$w'$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = vert--ee--w};
\pic [draw, <-, "$\gamma$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = w--ee--phi};
\pic [draw, ->, "$\phi=w'-\gamma$", angle eccentricity=1.3,angle radius=1.2cm] {angle = vert--ee--phi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about creating two different pictures? All the empty spaces between pictures will be omitted. If you are not talking about the empty space between two shapes, I did not understand your question and I want you to be more clear in your question.

Comment: I have revised my question. I think it's clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the `overlay` option:

```
\node[overlay] (O) at (2.5,2) {O};
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[overlay] (O) at (2.5,2) {O};  %%node O

\path (O) ++(-60:5) coordinate (ee); 
\path (O) ++(-120:5) coordinate (oo); 
\draw[dashed][line width=.3pt] (oo) arc (-120:-60:5);


\path (O) ++(-60:4.5) coordinate (eeu); 
\path (O) ++(-120:4.5) coordinate (oou); 
\draw[dashed][line width=.3pt] (oou) arc (-120:-60:4.5);

\path (O) ++(-60:5.5) coordinate (eed); 
\path (O) ++(-120:5.5) coordinate (ood);
\draw[dashed][line width=.3pt] (ood) arc (-120:-60:5.5);
\draw[dashed][line width=.3pt] (ood) -- (oou);
\draw[dashed][line width=.3pt] (eed) -- (eeu);
\draw[-latex] (oo) -- ++(0:1) coordinate [label=below:$x$] (xx);
\draw[-latex] (oo) -- ++(90:1) coordinate [label=right:$y$] (yy);

\path (O) ++(-63:4.5) coordinate (eeuT); 
\path (O) ++(-117:4.5) coordinate (oouT); 
\draw[solid][line width=.5pt] (oouT) arc (-117:-63:4.5);

\path (O) ++(-57.5:5.5) coordinate (eedT); 
\path (O) ++(-122.5:5.5) coordinate (oodT);
\draw[solid][line width=.5pt] (oodT) arc (-122.5:-57.5:5.5);
\draw[solid][line width=.5pt] (oodT) -- (oouT);
\draw[solid][line width=.5pt] (eedT) -- (eeuT);


\draw[solid][line width=.3pt] (ee) -- ++(90:1.2) coordinate(vert);
\draw[solid][line width=.3pt] (ee) -- ++(120:1.2) coordinate(w);
\draw[solid][line width=.3pt] (ee) -- ++(145:1.2) coordinate(phi);
\pic [draw, ->, "$w'$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = vert--ee--w};
\pic [draw, <-, "$\gamma$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = w--ee--phi};
\pic [draw, ->, "$\phi=w'-\gamma$", angle eccentricity=1.3,angle radius=1.2cm] {angle = vert--ee--phi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```